# How to change text format of text area in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.6

I have taken a rich text editor in text area. When I edit the text and perform operations like bold, italic etc. it does not affect the text. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It have to work, can you post us some sample code about how you did that, i'm not getting any idea.

You can perform this operation in Textarea using TLF check these examples.

[TLf Editor in Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/25/exporting-a-textflow-object-in-flex-4/)

[TLF Editor](http://asciiworks.net/2010/08/simple-tlf-text-editor-released/)

[Rich Text Editor Adobe Docx](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_10.html)